# Multipart image upload not working in swift with alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

Image upload along with parameters not working with the below code i tried.

```
let testImage = UIImage(named: "sayHi")

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Content-lenth" : "\(testImage?.pngData()?.count ?? 0)",
    "Accept": "application/json",
]

AF.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        
        multipartFormData.append("10".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "pickerId")
        multipartFormData.append("100".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "walkerRfid")
        multipartFormData.append(testImage!.pngData()!, withName: "photo" , fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    },
    to: "https://zb9.amazonaws.com/data/savePickerData", method: .post , headers: headers)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .response { resp in
        switch resp.result{
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case.success( _):
            print("Response after upload Img: \(resp.result)")
        }
    }
```

Response :

```
 responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 502))
```

Comment: Your server returned 502 (Bad gateway), its part that you're trying to connect seems to be inaccessible.

Comment: but the same thing is working in post man

Comment: Didn't you ask that question earlier with `URLSession` instead of Alamofire? I asked there if you could share the Postman generated Swift code, see if it works if you put it as such in your app, and then share it with us to compare what could be the difference?

Comment: hey @larme, same thing with post man generated code too

Comment: Are you saying that the Postman generated Swift code doesn't work either?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: Are you testing on Simulator or real device? The simulator should use the same "IP config" (DNS, etc.) than your Postman, so maybe if you are using a real device it's because of that?

Comment: i am using simulator @Larme